# Show/hid divs without information contained in the divs from displaying while loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

Hello I am using the below code...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
$('#show_advertisement').click(function() {
    $('#gallery_logos').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_illustrations').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_webdesign').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_advertisments').fadeIn('slow');
});
$('#show_logo').click(function() {
    $('#gallery_advertisments').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_illustrations').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_webdesign').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_logos').fadeIn('slow');
});
   $('#show_illustration').click(function() {
    $('#gallery_advertisments').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_webdesign').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_logos').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_illustrations').fadeIn('slow');
});
   $('#show_web').click(function() {
    $('#gallery_advertisments').fadeOut('slow');
     $('#gallery_illustrations').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#gallery_logos').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_webdesign').fadeIn('slow');
});
$('#show_advertisement').trigger('click');

         });
</script>
```

Basically I am showing multiple lightbox galleries contained in four divs that are stacked on top of each other and are all shown/hidden when you click on four links on the page. The problem I am having is that when the page loads I get a brief view of all the content on the four divs that then fades to the show_advertisement div. While it's only a minor problem I feel that it makes the page look unprofessional. 
I have no experience with Javascript or jQuery but I am trying to learn, if you could help me out I would really appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('#gallery_logos, #gallery_illustrations, #gallery_webdesign').hide();
$('#gallery_advertisments').show();
```

instead of `$('#show_advertisement').trigger('click');`

Comment: It's `#gallery_webdesig(n)` but other than that +1

Comment: With this you might still see the `#gallery_logos, #gallery_illustrations, #gallery_webdesig` for a very brief moment. This should be hidden in CSS

Answer (score 0):

To make sure all is hidden (but `#gallery_advertisments`) when your page loads, set this to your CSS:

```
#gallery_logos,
#gallery_illustrations,
#gallery_webdesign { 
   display: none;
}

#gallery_advertisments { 
   display: block;
}
```

And simplify your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
  $('#show_advertisement').click(function() {
    $('#gallery_logos, #gallery_illustrations, #gallery_webdesign').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_advertisments').fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $('#show_logo').click(function() {
    $('#gallery_advertisments, #gallery_illustrations, #gallery_webdesign').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_logos').fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $('#show_illustration').click(function() {
    $('#gallery_advertisments, #gallery_webdesign, #gallery_logos').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_illustrations').fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $('#show_web').click(function() {
    $('#gallery_advertisments, #gallery_illustrations, #gallery_logos').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#gallery_webdesign').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
</script>
```